# Exibir link de excluir apenas se não houver categorias filhas

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo um banco de dados com as seguintes colunas:

```
|id|id_pai|nome_categoria|
+--+------+--------------+
|01|   0  | Eletronicos  |
|--+------+--------------+
|02|   01 | Notebook     |
|--+------+--------------+
|03|   0  | Livros       |
+--+------+--------------+
|04|  03  | Romance      |
+--+------+--------------+
```

Quero retornar uma tabela em html com nome apenas da  categoria pai e um link pra excluir, porém o link só poderá aparecer se  a categoria não tiver categoria filha.

Comment: Quem seria a categoria pai? id_pai? e a categoria filha? Não ficou claro.

Comment: Quando a categoria for Pai, o id_pai é 0. Quando a categoria for filha o id_pai é o número do id da categoria Pai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que seria algo como:

```
SELECT id, nome_categoria
FROM categoria
WHERE id NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT id_pai
     FROM categoria);
```